# How to pass dynamic value into xpath in selenium, java?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a website, where i open contract and get the unique contractId. Then, i need to go to other page and search this id in table with pagination. I wrote code which goes to next page if this requesid(it's a link) is not found and if it exist, it just opens this requestId. But there is a problem with initialization of webelement where i'm trying add dynamic value. Selenium gives error below and i have no idea how to solve it

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='link__text' and text()='222254']/../../..//input"}
> (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.72)

contractId is the variable where i store dynamic value that changes every test run. This is how the code looks like:

```
    csecp.waitForElementVisibility(csecp.getContractStatusEmergencyChangeHeader());
        int totalPages = Integer.parseInt(csecp.getTotalPagesString().getText());
        for(int i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
            csecp.sleep(500);
            if (**csecp.prepareWebElementWithDynamicXpath(csecp.getContractDynamicValue(),contractId).isDisplayed()**) {
                csecp.prepareWebElementWithDynamicXpath(csecp.getContractDynamicValue(),contractId).click();
                csecp.waitForElementVisibility(csecp.getConfirmAMLApprovalButton());
                csecp.getConfirmAMLApprovalButton().click();
                break;
            }
            csecp.waitForElementVisibility(csecp.getNextPageButton());
            csecp.getNextPageButton().click();
        }
```

This is how i'm trying to pass dynamic valueinto xpath

```
   private String contractDynamicValue = "//span[@class='link__text' and text()='xxxxx']/../../..//input";

    public WebElement prepareWebElementWithDynamicXpath (String xpathValue, String substitutionValue ) {

        return getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpathValue.replace("xxxxx", substitutionValue)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See the xpath that you are using is

```
//span[@class='link__text' and text()='xxxxx']/../../..//input
```

and if you wanna make `xxxxx` as dynamic, you could do following :-

```
string sub_value = "222254";
//span[@class='link__text' and text()='"+sub_value+"']/../../..//input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define and use this XPath locator as following:

```java
String contractDynamicValue = "//span[@class='link__text' and text()='%s']/../../..//input";

public WebElement prepareWebElementWithDynamicXpath (String xpathTemplate, String substitutionValue ) {
    String xpath = String.format(xpathTemplate,substitutionValue);
    return getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always the best solution to get element by text and the following element. For dynamic elements, you can use XPath like

```
 //div[.='Dummy_text']/following::span[text()='test_text']
```

You can see some tutorials from here
https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html